# texture coordinate imperial units

Tags: units, texture-coordinates

I understand that by default, 1 blender unit = 1 meter.

Setting "Scene Properties -> Units -> Unit System" allows me to model in some other units.  I tend to use inches.

So that's worked fine for all my mesh modeling, but now that I'm trying to make textures, I need those to be scaled properly as well.  However, my tests have shown that my procedural textures still use 1 BU = 1 meter, despite my scene properties settings.  Nothing in the units panel seems to affect the texture scaling at all.

The attached blend file shows what I mean.  I created a procedural texture which creates a border where the X coordinate is equal to 1 (using object coordinates).  The units in my file are set to inches, with unit scale set to 1/12 = 0.08333.

The bottom rectangle is 4" wide, the top one is 10" wide (object scales are normalized to one).  I would expect, if everything is working in inches, that the border would show up at the 1" mark on both objects.  But in fact the border appears at 3.28", which is suspiciously similar to 1 meter = 3.28 ft.

[image]

Is there an easy, canonical way to set Blender to work entirely in one unit system?

[image]

Comment: shall I interpret the silence as a "no"?